# Authentication and key distribution in bitcoin

Tags: bitcoind, protocol, encryption, cryptography, authentication

After going through the [bitcoin protocol documentation](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation) it is still unclear to me how the bitcoin client is authenticated. Where can I find an overview of what the client sends and receives on the wire during authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "authentication" in bitcoin protocol. It is not encrypted also.

You can use wireshark to investigate handshake packets

Comment: That is what I basically wanted to know.

Comment: See http://www.righto.com/2014/02/bitcoins-hard-way-using-raw-bitcoin.html